# Combinatorics -average value

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Q:determine the average value of**

$\ i_1i_2 +i_2i_3 +i_3i_4 + .....+i_{10}i_1$

taken over all permutations $i_1,i_2,....i_{10}$ of  1,2,3...10.

Here is how i tried :-

$\ i_1$ can take values from 1,2,3...10. So the avg value is $\ (1+2+3..+10)/10 =5.5 $

same is the average value of $\ i_2,i_3,.....i_{10}$

average value of $\ i_1i_2= 5.5*5.5=30.25$

so the average value of the given expression shall be $\ 30.25*10=302.5$

I am quite sure that my answer is incorrect, but any idea about how to proceed shall be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the formula,

> $$\sum_{i=a}^{b}\sum_{j=a}^{b} a_ib_j=\sum_{i=j=a}^{b}a_ib_j+\sum_{i\neq j}^{a\to b}a_ib_j$$

We want 
$$\sum_{a\neq b}^{1\to 10} i_ai_b=\sum_{a=1}^{10}\sum_{b=1}^{10}i_ai_b-\sum_{a=b=1}^{10}i_ai_b$$
$$=(\sum_{a=1}^{10}i_a)(\sum_{b=1}^{10}i_b)-\sum_{a=1}^{10}i_a^2$$
$$=(i_1+i_2+i_3+\cdots+i_{10})(i_1+i_2+i_3+\cdots+i_{10})-(i_1^2+i_2^2+i_3^2+\cdots+i_{10}^2)$$

So average value equals,
$$=\frac{1}{90}((i_1+i_2+i_3+\cdots+i_{10})^2-(i_1^2+i_2^2+i_3^2+\cdots+i_{10}^2))$$

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: Shouldn't there be 9 in the denominator instead of 90.